# ElastAlert : Access to the Elastic search exposed by Oauth2

Tags: elastalert

Context :
ElastAlert v0.1.29 included in Container Docker on OpenShift Orchestrator
Elasticsearch 2.4.4 exposed by Openshift agregate_logging (with Oauth2)

Hello,

From Elastalert, i want to connect to Elasticsearch.
The authenticate of Elastic use oauth2.
The oauth2 requires the X-Proxy-Remote-User and the token in the header of the requests :
Ex:
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "X-Proxy-Remote-User: $(oc whoami)" -H "X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1" https://es.example.test/_cat/indices

I believe that ElastAlert doesn't support the authenticate Oauth2 by token. Can you confirm?
Effectively, i don't think that client_key and client_cert tls options they are compatible ?

Thanks for your help

Regards
Loïc

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read of the code, no, it only supports basic auth. This would be a nice feature if someone had the time to contribute.